# Ubuntu extreme slow down after I run more than two .py scripts in parallel, does not happen on Windows

Tags: 18.04, scripts, python

So I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my home computer with the intent of doing my Machine Learning work.
Before my work load on Windows OS involved me running a few (10 or so) python scripts over night directly in VS-code. I would run each one in their own terminal with the ctrl+shift+5 command. The code involves training some neural network and constantly saving parameters to different folders, without any interference between the different scripts I am running. I am using conda but the code I am running as of now only relies on the cpu as the networks are small.
So I did the same thing last night using Ubuntu only running 4 terminals over night, but to my surprise they did not even finish. I can not give the exact timing but it is extremely noticeable, I can not use this OS for my work at the state I have things right now. I tried testing to see if it worked better when I ran them directly from the terminal and not in vscode, but there is no difference. I did notice that the slow down happens right when I go from running two terminals, to adding the third one. Although my CPU usage is at 100% by then on all threads, Windows runs these scripts much faster (10x at least.) I also checked to make sure this problem was only happening when I used the CPU to train my networks, and that is the case. Using the GPU I get the same performance as my Windows OS.

I have checked to make sure there is no bottleneck on the RAM or cache using *lscpu* as well as *free -m* and *top* but I can not find anything. This issue seems very specific and I have not found a solution searching the web. Sorry if this doesn't belong on this thread, but it would be nice to resolve this as I would like to continue using Ubuntu for my work.

Here are some specifics for my system:

```
  OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS x86_64 
  Host: Z390 AORUS MASTER 
  Kernel: 5.3.0-62-generic 
  Uptime: 12 mins 
  Packages: 1773 
  Shell: bash 4.4.20 
  Resolution: 2560x1440 
  DE: GNOME 3.28.4 
  WM: GNOME Shell 
  WM Theme: Adwaita 
  theme: Ambiance [GTK2/3] 
  cons: Ubuntu-mono-dark [GTK2/3] 
  Terminal: gnome-terminal 
  CPU: Intel i9-9900K (16) @ 5.000GHz 
  GPU: NVIDIA NVIDIA Corporation GV102 
  Memory: 2468MiB / 32046MiB
```

Also here is the output of top for the processes while I am running them:

```
PID  USER      PR   NI   VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU   %MEM   TIME   COMMAND
5310 mark      20   0 6451952 203204 116764 R 400.0  0.6  14:32.12 python                                                                                 
5403 mark      20   0 6439128 194616 114152 R 398.0  0.6  13:40.28 python                                                                                 
5446 mark      20   0 6439108 194504 114040 R 397.0  0.6  13:25.91 python                                                                                 
5359 mark      20   0 6439408 195596 115000 R 394.0  0.6  14:08.41 python
```

Comment: Are Windows and Ubuntu installed on separate machines? Are you using Ubuntu in WSL?

Comment: They are installed on the same machine, on two seperate SSDs. Both M.2 slots have the same number of PCIE lanes running to the CPU. They are also the same SSD. Also I just checked by running the same 4 files on the GPU and I did not experience this bottleneck.